# List NewForm.aspx opens a different form

Tags: web-part, custom-list, custom-form, application-pages, display-form

I hope someone could help in my case:

We have SharePoint Server-2010 which was migrated to SharePoint Server-2013 recently, and my assignment is to create custom List with Application page which invokes Web Part.
Our secured environment prohibits use of SharePoint Designer, and functions only as .wsp deployment.

In the solution we have many projects, so I was able to find a similar project and copy it and work from this once (modifying every reference and names of display forms and so on), But at the end, when I deploy the project and open NewForm, it opens the old Web Part of the copied project. And I looked every inch of the code and could not find the reference why it does this. 
Had someone experienced this?

Help would be appreciated, since I have a deadline to catch, and just spent 1 week in it.

I could provide the code but would need pointer what part of the code to examine.

[image: Twin forms]
**Thank you so much**

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of this to happen is may be your old solution still exist in your site collection.Try deactivating it and activate your new solution.

Please let me know if this helped you or not or you are facing some other issue.

Thanks